# resources that work in iOS and Android

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

How can I setup my cocos2d-X v3 in a way that the resources folder work for iOS and Android at the same time?

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-space-game), but it seens its solutions didn't worked

I run this on proj.android, but Eclipse doesn't see Resources folder

```
ln -s ../Resources ./Resources
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a soft symlink properly

it's not

`ln -s ../Resources ./Resources`

but rather something like:

`ln -s <the path to what you want> <symlink Name>`

so for android:

`ln -s /Users/Jason/AppResources assets`

Comment: This way, inside assets folder there will be a Resources folder. When I reference an image inside Resources, how should I do?beucase on ios version the reference will be just "img.png", but on Android the reference will be "Resources/img.png". How can I handle this?

Comment: no it wont because you just told the symlink it was called assets. Unless you are hardcoding the "Resources/" Can you post a small example of maybe creating a sprite so I can see your code? Just want to give you the best answer.